# How does gcc find libc.so.6?

Tags: c++, c, gcc, glibc, libc

sscanf_test. is a simple C file and it can works successfully with a simple compile command.

```
$gcc sscanf_test.c -I/si/usr/aa/include/arch -o sscanf_test_2
```

When I add some -L options as follows, it doesn't work.

```
$gcc sscanf_test.c -I/si/usr/aa/include/arch -o sscanf_test_2  -m64  -L$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs/
/tmp/ccq1Z6T1.o：function ‘main’：
sscanf_test.c:(.text+0x32)：undefined reference to ‘__isoc99_sscanf’
sscanf_test.c:(.text+0xf8)：undefined reference to ‘__isoc99_sscanf’
sscanf_test.c:(.text+0x1e4)：undefined reference to‘__isoc99_sscanf’
collect2: ld return 1
```

And when I add /lib64/libc.so to the compile command, it compiles successfully.

```
$gcc sscanf_test.c -I/si/usr/aa/include/arch -o sscanf_test_2  -m64  -L$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs/ /lib64/libc.so.6
$
```

It maybe caused by $ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs/ which contains a libc.so.6 which may not be right.

```
ETS:~ # find / -name libc.so.6
/home2/oracle/product/11gr2/db/lib/stubs/libc.so.6
/lib/libc.so.6
/lib64/libc.so.6
```

But I wonder why gcc can't recognize other paths. And I run it on another machine, which has a similar env to this system (SUSE 11 SP3), gcc version(4.3) , glibc version(2.11), it works normally with `gcc sscanf_test.c -I/si/usr/aa/include/arch -o sscanf_test_2  -m64  -L$ORACLE_HOME/precomp/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/ -L$ORACLE_HOME/lib/stubs/`

It's really inexplicable. Is it caused by some env arguments that I am not setting correctly? Can you give me some suggestions?

Comment: What exactly is inexplicable? That gcc links to the first file named libc.so.6 it finds in the libraries search path? What other behaviour would you expect?

Comment: @n.m. I expect it could find all libc.so.6 not just only the path I remind so that it may compile successful.I add the lib path just want to add the third party libraries but not including the gcc standard lib

Comment: "all libc.so.6" nope, doesn't work this way. "just want to add the third party libraries" If you add a search path, gcc will find everything under that path including its standard libs. If you need to add specific libraries, add them with their full path, not with the -l and -L flags.

Comment: @n.m. not exactly specific , just some oracle libraries or libxml2 libraries. It's puzzeled me that why I could run normally on another machine.For that, I guest it may have some configuration I not set correctly